# Get Read and Publish Permissions in one request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

Before you all say it's not possible, open up the Spotify app and hit the signin with Facebook button.

I'm wondering how they did it, and how I can get "publish_stream" and basic permissions/email in one request.

Also, is it possible for me to reopen a Facebook session using the Facebook SDK if I have certain info from the last session (last time they used the app)?

**EDIT** -SCREENSHOTS BELOW FOR THE MUSICALLY AVERT

[image: Spotify magic]

Comment: Just because its possible for Spotify doesn't mean the functionality is extended to all other apps. Know any other apps that can open 3rd party computer applications directly from FB?

Comment: Are you suggesting that Spotify is piggybacking off Facebook to offset its royalty streaming payments, and that Zuckerberg is promoting the partnership due to his long-acknowledged love for P2P streaming services?             ...that's crazy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What ever you saw on Spotify is not the outcome of `publish_stream` .What they have used is the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/)

Open graph concepts involves integrating actions of the app with the FB activity post and share with the users through the application they use. Read more about it at the above mentioned link.

---

Edits ***Explanation***:
[Check the Open Graph Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/)

Sample Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements StatusCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(this);
        open.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        open.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "publish_actions", "user_birthday", "user_hometown"}));
        open.setCallback(this);
        Session s = new Session(this);
        s.openForPublish(open);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(Session.getActiveSession()!=null)
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

This activity will show this (if the user is not logged in):

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer. Try to add the permission `publish_actions` I will edit this answer and add a test.

Comment: i exactly trying to do the same FB login(like pinterest) with permission email,basic_info,publish_action in a single request.implemented above code but unable to do so...plz help...

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have created an instance for OpenRequest and I have set permissions for it.

```
Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) 
{
    Session session = new Session.Builder(context).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    currentSession = session;
}

if (currentSession.isOpened()) 
{
    //Do whatever u want. User has logged in
}
else if(!currentSession.isOpened())
{
    //Ask for username and password
    OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(context);

    op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
    op.setCallback(null);

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("publish_stream");
    op.setPermissions(permissions);

    Session session = new Builder(InvitePartners.this).build();
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
    session.openForPublish(op);
}
```

It may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I just set it separately in the onCreate Method.

```
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new 
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("read_stream"));
    Session.getActiveSession().requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application dashboard. then click edit app. now in left side of the page u will see `Permission`. click it. a new page will come. find out `User & Friend Permissions:` box. here type `publish_actions`. now save.

now from your android app you can post story to facebook by login just once. i mean, just login using `LoginButton`,and try to post something. it should work.

let me know what happen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from my mobile app. I tried with both my own implementation of session management (openSessionForPublish without already having read permissions) and with the tools that the Facebook SDK provided (com.facebook.widget.LoginButton and setting Read and Publish permissions).

Both throw errors saying you can't request both at the same time.

Comment: Then it only prompts for the read permission. openSessionForRead("app_id", "permission_list")

Comment: r u using Facebook SDK 3.02 ? i have done this using 3.02 and `LoginButton`

Comment: I am. And they were on the same page like above?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is wondering about the second part of my question:

To reopen a Facebook session using the Facebook SDK use this code

```
if(Session.openActiveSession(this) == null) { //Haven't logged in yet
    openSessionForRead(getString(R.string.app_id), Arrays.asList("email"));
}
```

Facebook caches the token.