# FB login(like pinterest)using sdk 3.0 with permission email,basic_info,publish_action in a single request

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

[image]

is it possible for me to reopen a Facebook session using the Facebook SDK if I have certain info from the last session (last time they used the app)?

Comment: already checked this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143951/get-read-and-publish-permissions-in-one-request.