# Photos uploaded via Android is not approved on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I've been succeeded uploading a photo to Facebook via my Android app, which exists in the album created for my app, but the photo needs to be approved manually by the user, and Facebook said:

```
Would you like to add these photos to your album?
The photos below were uploaded from another application, you'll need to approve them.
```

It looks like this on Facebook:

[image]

By the way, I've added the `user_photos` permission. And here is the code for uploading:

```
public void uploadToFB(Uri photo){

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
    bundle.putString("url", "http://6269-9001.zippykid.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Cute-Dog-Wallpaper-Pictures.jpg");          

    new Request(
        session,
        "/me/photos",
        bundle,
        HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

In the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoggedMainActivity.class));
    } else {
        showLoginFragment();            
    }
}

private void showLoginFragment(){
    LoginFragment login=new LoginFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, login)
        .commit();
}
```

And this is the LoginFragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private LoginButton authButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, 
            container, false);
    authButton=(LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos","publish_stream","read_stream"));
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Please attach the code, that you have used for publishing the photos to Facebook.

Comment: @Salman Ayub, Okay, it's added now

Comment: Are you using The Facebook Login Widget ? For Authentication ? I think you are missing some permissions on it.

Comment: @Salman Ayub Yes I'm using the FB login for authentication, the only permission I added is 'user_photos' permission, do you know what's else should I add?

Comment: You need `publish_stream` permission to upload photo/video, see: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `publish_stream` permission on Your `Facebook Login Widget`

Here is a demonstration of how to add that permission:

```
/*LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_photos"));
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_stream","read_stream"));*/
```

Just Add these permissions to your Login Widget and everything should work fine.

**Edit:** 
`Setting up Read and Publish Permissions together :` 
[Get Read and Publish Permissions in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143951/get-read-and-publish-permissions-in-one-request)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I got an error when adding permissions above, the error is: Cannot pass a publish or manage permission (publish_stream) to a request for read authorization. Any tips :)

Comment: Yes, i expected that :) You are having some conflicting permissions. Please post the initialization code of your Facebook Login Widget.

Comment: Hi, another error appears: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.android/com.example.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot call setReadPermissions after setPublishPermissions has been called.

Comment: I found a useful link regarding this error, please check the updated answer. Thank You.