# Facebook SDK 4.x, setReadPermissions and setPublishPermissions

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I had source code:

```
List<String> listPermission = Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile", "user_friends", "read_page_mailboxes", "read_insights");
        List<String> listPermissionPublish = Arrays.asList("manage_pages", "publish_actions");

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(listPermission);
        loginButton.setPublishPermissions(listPermissionPublish);


        loginButton.registerCallback(((HomeActivity) getActivity()).getCallbackManager(), new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
```

I using Facebook SDK 4.0 for Android.
But i had a problem getReadPermission and getPublishPermission on one request.

I see in: [Get Read and Publish Permissions in one request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143951/get-read-and-publish-permissions-in-one-request)

However in Facebook SDK 4.x is Session Removed.

Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 1):

You can not ask for both permissions simultaneously.  First get read permission and then ask for publish permission. I am calling this method from a button listener.

```
void requestPublishPermissions() {
    // Requesting publish permissions
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
            this,
            Arrays.asList("user_managed_groups", "user_groups"));

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sp. I'm closed that project! :)