# Facebook sharing in Libgdx with 4.x Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have problem with sharing something with FacebookSDK in a LibGDX Android application. If I click the share button and share something I get back `Sharer.Result` `null` (so the post is not shared, but in reality it is!), which is the same result I get when I cancel sharing.

Here is my code:

```
 Android Manifest
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMYFACEBOOKID"
              android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
              android:exported="true"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
              android:configChanges=
                  "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

AndroidLauncher.java (activity that starts the whole app):

```
  @Override
protected void onResume() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    super.onResume();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebookPluginAndroid.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

facebookPluginAndroid is my class that have CallBackManager:

this.callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

And  the `share()` function (that launches when I press the share button):

```
 public void share(final FacebookPluginListener facebookPluginListener){
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(context);

    final ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/SOME URL TO MY SITE"))
            .build();
    if(shareDialog.canShow(content)){
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                System.out.println("share SHARED " + result.getPostId());
                if(result.getPostId()!=null)
                    facebookPluginListener.getFacebookShareListener().onShareSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("share CANCEL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                System.out.println("share ERROR");
            }


        },121);

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? What must I do to properly share content with FacebookSDK?

@EDIT:
FacebookPluginAndroid.java:

```
public class FacebookPluginAndroid {
private Activity context;
private ShareDialog shareDialog;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LikeDialog likeDialog;

public FacebookPluginAndroid(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

public void share(final FacebookPluginListener facebookPluginListener) {


    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(context);
    shareDialog.setShouldFailOnDataError(true);
    final ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/SOME URL"))
            .build();
    if (shareDialog.canShow(content)) {
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                System.out.println("share SHARED " + result.getPostId());
                if (result.getPostId() != null)
                    facebookPluginListener.getFacebookShareListener().onShareSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("share CANCEL");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                System.out.println("share ERROR");
            }


        }, 121);

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                shareDialog.show(content);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void like(final FacebookPluginListener facebookPluginListener) {
    likeDialog = new LikeDialog(context);
    final LikeContent content = new LikeContent.Builder()
            .setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/SOMEURL")
            .build();


    if (likeDialog.canShow(content)) {
        likeDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LikeDialog.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LikeDialog.Result result) {
                System.out.println("like success! android LIKE" + result.getData());

                if (result.getData().getBoolean("object_is_liked"))
                    facebookPluginListener.getFacebookLikeListener().onLikeSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("like cancel! android LIKE");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                System.out.println("like error! android LIKE");
            }


        }, 123);

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                likeDialog.show(content);
            }
        });
    }
}

public CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return callbackManager;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your FacebookPluginAndroid class?

Comment: @NikoYuwono edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post_id response only available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story.

U need add `loginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));`

Comment: so I can't use "like" or "share" without login button?

Comment: @taulus how do you use share? if the user is not logged in?

Comment: not always - share dialog is showing up and if user is not logged in he must log in in this dialog, then share.

Comment: @taulus check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143951/get-read-and-publish-permissions-in-one-request?answertab=oldest#tab-top) , mb help u

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution for my problem was: change facebook id in application. This ID was changed (!!!) after send to review by facebook team, and I didn't notice it.

What's more if you want to share something you must use in application LoginButton (from facebook sdk) and then ShareButton (always from facebook sdk). In login button you must send permission that PeDuCka wrote above.
If you create ShareDialog with registered callback manager,in method onSuccess(ShareDialog.Result result) result.getPostId() will be always null until you add on facebook config page permission to publish_actions (and team must review it [5 days remaining time]) and you must test it with PeDuCKA code.
In my opinion sdk of facebook is very very very bad documented. The worst I have ever seen (many of contradictory informations).